# Bar Chart With Tooltip in objective c

Tags: objective-c, bar-chart

How can I achieve Bar chart with tooltip when finger drag on bar chart.I want to like bar chart which is in attached image.

Please suggest me any library for bar chart with tooltip in objective c.

[image: Bar chart with tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

When comes to iOS plotting I think you would like to give a try to Daniel Cohen iOS Charts:

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Fully customizable and lots of styles and chart views, swift and objective-c, also available for android. I would recommend you to take a look to the demo project to get a full overview of how this library works.

The implementation of a bar chart with custom view would be something like this:

```
MPBarsGraphView *barPlot1 = [MPPlot plotWithType:MPPlotTypeBars frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    barPlot1.minValue = 0;
    barPlot1.maxValue = 35;
    barPlot1.waitToUpdate = YES;
    barPlot1.showTopLabels = YES;
    barPlot1.topValues = @[@"25.7",@"27.8",@"28.7",@"31.2"];
    barPlot1.values = @[@25.7,@27.8,@28.7,@31.2];
    barPlot1.graphColor = [UIColor yourColor];
    barPlot1.detailView = [UIView yourView];
    [self.view addSubview:barPlot1];
```